# elasticsearch установка на ubuntu 20 или docker

Tags: elasticsearch

Пытаюсь начать изучение elasticsearch соответственно первым делом надо его установить.

поставил elasticsearch + kibana с помощью этого замечательного руководства:
https://serveradmin.ru/ustanovka-i-nastroyka-elasticsearch-logstash-kibana-elk-stack/#Ubuntu_Debian

следующим шагом нужно установить **Elastic Enterprise Search**
попробовал руководство того же автора:
https://serveradmin.ru/ustanovka-elastic-enterprise-search/

но здесь уже меня ждала неудача - не завелось.

Ладно, попробовал как мне казалось самый простой путь - поставить в Docker

Вот тут ясным английским языком написано что надо делать:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html

Всего навсего надо набрать
docker pull
потом
docker run

Вроде бы в двух строчках ошибиться никак не возможно ?
Однако прямо сразу полезли ошибки
В SO написано что нужно увеличить лимит виртуальной памяти - увеличил.

Дальше если я правильно понял говорят что нужно в github взять docker compose и там внутри поправить конфигурационные файлы.

Подскажите пожалуйста как максимально простым способом поставить **Elastic Enterprise Search** (либо на Windows 10 либо на ubuntu 20 )

Answer (score 0):

Помог старинный совет - лучше читайте :)

Посмотрев то что написано после команды docker run увидел ошибку:

```
bootstrap check failure [1] of [1]: max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]
```

Сразу нашелся ответ на SO:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51445846/elasticsearch-max-virtual-memory-areas-vm-max-map-count-65530-is-too-low-inc

надо дать две команды:

```
wsl -d docker-desktop
sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
```

команды я давал когда docker был не запущен
Все завелось!